# Approximate formula for the probability than N random letter strings have m letters in common

Tags: probability

I'm writing a pattern-finding program.

Say I have a discrete distribution of letters over a 26-letter alphabet $\{p_1, p_2, ... p_{26}\}$. $N$ "words" of length $w_1, ... w_N$ are generated by choosing each letter independently from the distribution. I need a formula that can calculate the probability that this set of words contains at least $m$ letters in common. That is, there is some set of $m$ letters that appears in some place in each of the $N$ words. Letters that appear twice in each word count twice, etc., so for instance `that` and `stat` have 3 letters in common.

The formula can be very approximate. Within a factor of 10 is fine. I mostly need to distinguish $p > 0.05$ from $p < 0.01$. But, I also need it to run fairly quickly (say ~100 operations), so I probably can't loop over all $26Cm$ sets of $m$ letters. Also it's okay if it only works for smaller values, say $m < 6$, $w_i < 20$, $N < 20$.

Empirically, for uniform $p_j = 1/26$, uniform $w_i = 14$, and $m = 2$, then the probabilities are $0.99, 0.63, 0.19, 0.041, 0.0077, 0.0016, 0.00024$ for $N = 2$ through $8$. But none of my approximations gets anywhere close to this.

If this proves infeasible, I would also be interested in a version not allowing repetitions (in which case `that` and `stat` have 2 in common).

Comment: How are the lengths $w_i$ chosen?  Are they predetermined or are they also somehow random?  Is the set of $m$ letters a true set or is it perhaps a multiset that allows repetitions of letters?

Comment: The $w_i$'s are given. I need to compute a probability in terms of them. $p = p(m, w_1, ... w_N)$. As for the set of letters allowing repetitions, I'm interested in answers whichever way is easier, but the empirical probabilities I listed are for the version without repetitions.

Comment: Thank you (+1).  I had deduced that those empirical probabilities were without repetitions (I get the same values), but wanted these issues to be explicitly clear for all readers.

Comment: On second thought, I actually am more interested in the multiset version. I'm assuming that it's roughly close to the other version, at least for $m = 2$. I've updated the question to reflect this. Thank you.